# Declarative Http Interface IllegalStateException while generating a proxy implementing an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, httpexchange

I have such a client config, I am trying to create proxy client, but while creating a proxy i get `'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception. Cannot evaluate jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.toString()`. In my HTTP interface I have only one @GetExchange method.

`@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

```
@Bean
ClientInterface someClient() {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("some https")
            .defaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token")
            .build();
    HttpExchangeAdapter httpExchangeAdapter;
    HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builderFor(WebClientAdapter.create(webClient))
            .build();
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(ClientInterface.class);
}`
```

I want to create a proxy client in order to make an HTTP exchange.